# How to create an H2+flyway test database in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway, in-memory-database

I have a spring boot project where I want to test my controller.I use MySql database for production but want an in memory database for running the testcases.I use Flyway for versioning database migration.I want my test database to use the same versioning.Can someone please help me with a way to do that?

This is what my application.properties in src/test/resources folder looks like:

```
# Database Properties
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.database.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
security.basic.enabled:false

spring.datasource.username:sa
spring.datasource.password:

# Flyway Properties
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

This is my Test File:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration
public class PermissionsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void existentUserCanGetTokenAndAuthenticationAndAlsoExtractPermissions() throws Exception {
        String username = "Srishti";
        String body = "{" + "\"username\":\"" + username + "\"}";

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/authenticate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(body)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/permission").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + response))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print()).andReturn();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/permission/9").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + response))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print()).andReturn();
    }
}
```

And this is the output that I get currently get:

```
2020-09-06 19:30:54.481  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.t.L.PermissionsControllerTest          : Starting PermissionsControllerTest on DGKDSQ13 with PID 26936 (started by SrishtiChawla in C:\Users\srishtichawla\Desktop\LCTraining\LCTraining)
2020-09-06 19:30:54.483  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.t.L.PermissionsControllerTest          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-06 19:30:55.599  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-09-06 19:30:55.600  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.670  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.LOBRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.672  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.PermissionsRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.674  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.ProductCategoryRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.677  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.RolesRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.679  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.ScoringModelSuiteRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.681  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.training.LCtraining.repository.UserRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.682  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 74ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.694  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-09-06 19:30:55.695  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-06 19:30:55.762  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-06 19:30:56.308  INFO 26936 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@1e5eb20a' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-06 19:30:56.325  INFO 26936 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-06 19:30:57.018  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2020-09-06 19:30:57.032  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-06 19:30:57.033  INFO 26936 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-09-06 19:30:57.216  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-06 19:30:57.216  INFO 26936 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2708 ms
2020-09-06 19:30:57.353  WARN 26936 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-09-06 19:30:57.509  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.4.4 by Redgate
2020-09-06 19:30:57.515  INFO 26936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-06 19:30:57.746  INFO 26936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-06 19:30:57.773  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
2020-09-06 19:30:57.864  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 9 migrations (execution time 00:00.036s)
2020-09-06 19:30:57.883  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2020-09-06 19:30:57.955  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2020-09-06 19:30:57.970  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1 - createTables
2020-09-06 19:30:58.100  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.2 - inservalues
2020-09-06 19:30:58.144  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.3 - altertable
2020-09-06 19:30:58.183  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.4 - INSERTVALUES2
2020-09-06 19:30:58.216  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.5 - insertvalues3
2020-09-06 19:30:58.241  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.6 - ALTERTABLE
2020-09-06 19:30:58.264  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.7 - Altertablelob
2020-09-06 19:30:58.293  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.8 - insertvals
2020-09-06 19:30:58.315  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.10 - uniquekey
2020-09-06 19:30:58.330  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 9 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.383s)
2020-09-06 19:30:58.541  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-06 19:30:58.639  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-06 19:30:58.711  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
2020-09-06 19:30:58.903  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-06 19:30:59.060  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-09-06 19:30:59.320  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2020-09-06 19:30:59.970  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-06 19:30:59.982  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-06 19:31:00.409  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-09-06 19:31:00.489  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c43e84e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5e62ca19, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@493968a9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@7bd694a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@322ab6ce, com.training.LCtraining.filter.JwtFilter@af9dd34, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6528d339, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3149409c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@21ce2e4d, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@780c0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7a8b7e11, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@11ee671f]
2020-09-06 19:31:01.178  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2020-09-06 19:31:01.179  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2020-09-06 19:31:01.195  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 16 ms
2020-09-06 19:31:01.298  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 51516 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-06 19:31:01.300  INFO 26936 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-06 19:31:01.785  INFO 26936 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-09-06 19:31:01.801  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.t.L.PermissionsControllerTest          : Started PermissionsControllerTest in 7.711 seconds (JVM running for 9.214)
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_9_, user0_.lob_id as lob_id4_9_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_9_, user0_.role_id as role_id5_9_, user0_.username as username3_9_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
2020-09-06 19:31:02.278  WARN 26936 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2020-09-06 19:31:02.279 ERROR 26936 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "user" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.user_id as user_id1_9_, user0_.lob_id as lob_id4_9_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_9_, user0_.role_id as role_id5_9_, user0_.username as username3_9_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=? [42102-200]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /authenticate
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"22"]
             Body = {"username":"Srishti"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.training.LCtraining.integration.UserRestController
           Method = com.training.LCtraining.integration.UserRestController#generateToken(AuthRequest)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"timestamp":"2020-09-06","message":"could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.user_id as user_id1_9_, user0_.lob_id as lob_id4_9_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_9_, user0_.role_id as role_id5_9_, user0_.username as username3_9_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement","details":"uri=/authenticate"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /authenticate
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"22"]
             Body = {"username":"Srishti"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.training.training.integration.UserRestController
           Method = com.training.training.integration.UserRestController#generateToken(AuthRequest)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"timestamp":"2020-09-06","message":"could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.user_id as user_id1_9_, user0_.lob_id as lob_id4_9_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_9_, user0_.role_id as role_id5_9_, user0_.username as username3_9_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement","details":"uri=/authenticate"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2020-09-06 19:31:02.656  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-06 19:31:02.659  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-06 19:31:02.659  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-09-06 19:31:02.664  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

The controllers are working fine on the production side.

This is my V1.1__createtable.sql file

```
create table permissions(
permissionID int not null auto_increment,
permissionTitle varchar(40) not null,
permissionDescription varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (permissionID),
UNIQUE (permissionTitle));


insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Create Role');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Edit Role');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Delete Role');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Create User');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Edit User');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Delete User');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Create LOB');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Edit LOB');
insert into permissions(permissionTitle) values('Delete LOB');
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `V1.1_createTables.sql`

Comment: @AlexShesterov I have added the sql file you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the logs, Flyway is executed successfully:

```
Flyway Community Edition 6.4.4 by Redgate
HikariPool-1 - Starting...
HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
Successfully validated 9 migrations (execution time 00:00.036s)
Creating Schema History table "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history" ...
Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1 - createTables
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.2 - inservalues
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.3 - altertable
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.4 - INSERTVALUES2
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.5 - insertvalues3
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.6 - ALTERTABLE
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.7 - Altertablelob
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.8 - insertvals
Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.10 - uniquekey
Successfully applied 9 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.383s)
```

You can see that 9 migrations are applied: createTables, inservalues, altertable, INSERTVALUES2, insertvalues3, ALTERTABLE, Altertablelob, insertvals, uniquekey.

*Is this list complete or are you expecting more migrations?*

The error you see later in the log comes from Hibernate, not from Flyway.
And it says:

```
Table "user" not found
```

Looking the migration names, I would expect that the `user` table is created by the `createTables` migration. But there's no `CREATE TABLE 'user'` statement in `V1.1__createTables.sql`.

Please double-check that all necessary tables are defined in your migrations. You should NOT alter old migrations. Instead, you can create new migrations for the missing tables and use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` syntax, so that it's compatible with existing production environment.

Comment: These are all the migrations and I have a table "user" defined later on.I figured out the issue on my own. I just had to change the url of the datasource to jdbc:h2:file:~/mydb.Don't know much how that made a difference though.Thankyou for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and my solution was described in a comment by @Srish. Changing my url from jdbc:h2:mem:[MYDB] to jdbc:h2:file:~/[MYDB] allowed flyway to successfully perform the migrations as well perform JPA's validation.